# converter array unidimensional em multidimensional associativo

Tags: php

o meu problema era converter um array em simples em um array associativo multidimensional,o array é assim:

```
$dados = array(1,"1minuto","seco",2,"3minutos","chuva");
```

como deu pra perceber são três tipos de dados que se repetem, as chaves são: volta, tempo, clima.

tentei usar o array_fill_keys(), porém é necessário que o número de chaves seja igual ao número itens.
Solucionei o problema da seguinte forma:

```
insira
 <?php

$dados = array(1,"1m","seco",2,"3m","chuva");
$i = 0;
$a = 0;
foreach($dados as $dado){

if($i === 0){
    $array[$a]['volta'] = $dado;
    $i++;

}elseif($i === 1){
    $array[$a]['tempo'] = $dado;
    $i++;
}elseif($i === 2){
    $array[$a]['clima'] = $dado;
    $i = 0;
    $a++;
}

}   
echo "<pre>";
print_r($array);
echo "</pre>";
```

Isso resolveu o meu problema, mas a dúvida é se existe alguma função que resolvesse isso sem precisar dessa ginástica toda? ou até mesmo uma forma de otimizar esse código?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a função [`array_chunk()`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-chunk.php) para dividir um array em arrays menores cujo o comprimento é um número determinado e a função [`array_combine()`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-combine.php) para combinar duas arrays onde uma se originam as chaves e a outra os valores:

```
<?php
$dados = [1, "1m", "seco", 2, "3m","chuva"];
$chaves = ["volta", "tempo", "clima"];
$resultado = [];

//Divide $dados em arrays de três elementos
foreach(array_chunk($dados, 3) as $valores){
  //Combina os valores com suas respectivas chave em um novo array e o adiciona ao resultado
  $resultado[] = array_combine($chaves, $valores);
}

print_r($resultado);
```

Resultando:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [volta] => 1
            [tempo] => 1m
            [clima] => seco
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [volta] => 2
            [tempo] => 3m
            [clima] => chuva
        )

)
```

Funcionando no Repli.it: https://repl.it/repls/YummyFeistyAlgorithm

Comment: obrigado pela ajuda, de fato dá certo, vc sabe dizer se há algum ganho de desempenho usando o array_chunck em vez do for() como o colega respondeu?

Comment: @MarcosVinicius, Se quer uma resposta abra outra pergunta, pois complexidade de tempo de algorítimos é uma assunto vasto. Por cima, nesse caso os dois algorítimos são tempo linear pois operam por todos os elementos da entrada. A diferença em ciclos é minima você tem que receber uma entrada absurdamente grande para sentir a diferença...

Comment: ..., mas em geral a regra(ambos algorítimos estejam optimizados ao máximo) é que um código empacotado em um único `for` é mais rápido que um cujo faça chamadas de funções pois a chamada de funções requerem um ciclo a mais para negociar com a pilha de chamadas de função. Porém essa diferença seria sentida quando a entrada for da ordem de TB e HB.  Para entradas pequenas é indiferente.

Answer (score 2):

Pode fazer de uma forma mais simples usando `for`:

```
$dados = array(1,"1minuto","seco",2,"3minutos","chuva");
for($x = $index = 0; $x < sizeof($dados); $x+=3, $index++){
   $array[$index]['volta'] = $dados[$x];
   $array[$index]['tempo'] = $dados[$x+1];
   $array[$index]['clima'] = $dados[$x+2];
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($array);
echo "</pre>";
```

Saída:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[Teste no IDEONE](https://ideone.com/yr1z89)

Comment: obrigado pela ajuda, de fato dessa forma simplificou o processo.

Comment: Não fiz essa observação antes pois não queria influenciar na opinião do AP mas essa resposta eu entendo como boa, eu não entendi o porque de ser sinalizada como de baixa qualidade. O autor da sinalização poderia esclarecer o motivo de sua classificação?

Comment: @AugustoVasques Cara, infelizmente aqui tá cheio de terroristas.